# Custom domain DNS config for Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, dns

I recently configured my Google App Engine app to have a custom domain. I set up my naked domain (myapp.com) by including a TXT record with host "@" and the value provided by Google in my DNS setup with my domain registrar. I then added the four "A" and four "AAAA" records provided by Google.

I then set up "www.myapp.com" using a CNAME record with host "www" and value "ghs.googlehosted.com.".

However, I've noticed that when I type "www.myapp.com" into my browser, I'm only directed to my app **sometimes**. Other times I'm redirected to the domain landing page of my registrar.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: The browser redirection depends on various DNS caches (browser app, your machine's OS, various machines in the network and DNS hierarchy), it may take a while for the DNS configuration changes to become effective in all these caches. Do you see the inconsistencies in the _same_ browser app instance?

Comment: Sorry, but could you please define same browser app instance?

Comment: I mean the same browser application/executable lifetime (i.e. not exited and restarted, or same browser running on some other device or some other browser type)